# Memory leak of temp param arrays

Tags: c++

```
void setCString(char* s){
   char* t = new char[strlen(s) + 1];
   strcpy(t, s);
   delete[] m_cstring;   //del old contents from member var
   m_cstring = t;
}

rA.setCString("Bii");
```

Isn't this a memory leak?  "Bii" is created in memory and a pointer to it (s) is passed to the function.  In the function a new allocation is made and the contents of the s array are copied to the new t array.

When the function ends, s goes out of scope and is deleted but the initial original array that s pointed to is not deleted.

If this is a memory leak, how can it be fixed (sticking to c string as array... no std::string)?

Comment: As long as you eventually `delete[] m_cstring` in your destructor, it isn't a leak.

Comment: `"Bii"` is a string literal and should not be `delete[]`'d, you're good there

Comment: What horrible compiler are you using that allows you to convert `const char *` into `char *`???

Comment: Ohh i know m_cstring isn't an issue because of deallocation as you state, I'm reffering to the original array "| B | i | i | \0 | created by rA.setCString("Bii"); We delete the only ref to it an we don't explicitly del the array nor does anything new point to it anymore. Notice we copy the elements (strcpy).

Comment: Killzone, gcc 7. Sorry good catch.  I did an experiment and forgot to put back the const.

Comment: vu1p3n0x, why is that? I don't understand. Are string literals placed in a special memory section that you can't/shouldn't delete from?  Is this some special case somehow?

Comment: @code in-short, yes. [String literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) are stored [statically](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) not dynamically (created with `new`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Loosing" the (probably sole) pointer to a string literal is not considered a memory leak, because string literals cannot be "freed" and its "allocated memory" reused. Actually freeing a string literal is undefined behaviour. So no "leak" in its common sense; just a string literal which might not be used any more.